# parallel requests through EventSource forced to be served sequentially

Tags: python, flask, eventsource

I have a flask server using yield to stream and EventSource on the client side to get data from server in real time. When two EventSource requests are made parallely to the server, they are being executed sequentially. How can i make them work parallely?

EDIT: I have tried both uwsgi with nginx and flask server.
The issue is with event source and not flask. My requests are being served fine. The part that goes through event source is being served sequentially.